# Match dot after year and remove it

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex to remove all the dots after a year in a string.

I know that to target years and year intervals I can use

```
\s*\d{4}(?:\s*-\s*\d{4})?
```

But how do I capture only the dot?

For instance, if I have "ABCD 2009. DEF" I want to get "ABCD 2009 DEF"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wrap the pattern you have with a capturing group and add `\.+` after it (to match one or more dots) and replace with `\1` (to put back the year into the resulting string):

```
re.sub(r'(\s*\d{4}(?:\s*-\s*\d{4})?)\.+', r'\1', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkn7id/1).

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage a zero-width positive lookbhind (`(?<=\b\d{4})`) to make sure that the `.` you want to replace is preceded by four digits:

```
In [1820]: str_ = 'ABCD 2009. DEF'                                                                                                                                                                          

In [1821]: re.sub(r'(?<=\b\d{4})\.', '', str_)                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1821]: 'ABCD 2009 DEF'

In [1822]: str_ = 'ABCD 2009. DEF 2019. FOO'                                                                                                                                                                

In [1823]: re.sub(r'(?<=\b\d{4})\.', '', str_)                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1823]: 'ABCD 2009 DEF 2019 FOO'
```